# level 3 nav not hiding when it should be

Tags: html, css

I'm turning a 2 level nav into a 3 level and running into a few difficulties.

The 3rd level displays where and as predicted but when the 'grandparent' is hovered over, not the parent of the items I want displayed.

I've been fooling around with the css for a while and I cannot get it to respond how I'd like.

Any help is appreciated.

There is a fiddle as my explanation might be somewhat lacking.

```
http://jsfiddle.net/6TGaf/
```

Code from fiddle:

```
    #nav{
    background: #bada55;
    width: 99%;
    margin-top:-5px;
}

#nav ul{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 40px;
}

#nav ul li{
    /*child elements positioned absolutley will be relative to this*/
    position: relative;
    border-top: 1px solid #e9e9e9;
    float: left;

}

#nav a{
    color: ghostwhite;
    padding: 12px 0px;
    /*fill hori space*/
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
/*apply transition to background property, taking 1s to change it
*/
    transition:padding 1s, background 1s;
    -moz-transition:padding 1s, background 1s;
    -webkit-transition:padding 1s, background 1s;
    -o-transition:padding 1s, background 1s;

    font-family:tahoma;

    font-size:13px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    padding-left:20px;
}

/*hover pseduo class*/
#nav a:hover{
    /*
    RGBA background for transparancy:
    last number(0.05) is the transparency
    */
    padding-left:35px;
    background: RGBA(255,255,255,0.05);
    color:#fff;
}

#nav ul li:hover ul{
    /*diplay when hovered*/
    display: block;
}

#nav ul ul{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 40px;
    border-top: 1px solid #e9e9e9;
    display: none;
    /*width: 304px;*/
    z-index: 1;
}

#nav ul ul li{
    width: 150px;
    background: #f1f1f1;
    border: 1px solid #e9e9e9;
    border-top: 0;
    /*float:left;*/

}

#nav ul ul li a{
    color:#000000;
    font-size:12px;
    text-transform:none;
}

#nav ul ul li a:hover {
    color:#929292;
}

/*3rd level...*/
#nav ul ul ul{
    position: absolute;
    left: 150px;
    top: 0px;
    border-top: 1px solid #e9e9e9;
    display: none;
    /*width: 304px;*/
    z-index: 1;
}

#nav ul ul ul li{
    width: 150px;
    background: #f1f1f1;
    border: 1px solid #e9e9e9;
    border-top: 0;
}

#nav ul ul ul li a{
    color:#000000;
    font-size:12px;
    text-transform:none;
}

#nav ul ul ul li a:hover {
color:#929292;
}

#nav ul ul li:hover ul{
/*diplay when hovered*/
display: block;
}

<nav id = "nav">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#">1.1</a>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">1.1.1</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">1.1.1.a</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">1.1.1.b</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

                <li><a href="#">1.1.2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">1.1.3</a></li>

            </ul>
        </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Welcome to codereview. Questions must contain working code for us to review it here. For questions regarding specific problems encountered while coding, try Stack Overflow. After your code is working you can edit this question for reviewing your working code.

Comment: @AseemBansal, Hi, the code works...but not how I want it to if that makes sense.

Comment: I'll rephrase. The code should be working in the way you want it to work. If it doesn't try stackoverflow. After it is working like you want you can edit this to get it reviewed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your css,

```
#nav ul li:hover ul{
   display: block;}
```

the above piece of code was displaying all the elements in the ul block on hover of 1st li element. In this case hovering 1.1. As the grandchild (1.1.1a) also belongs to the upper block ul, even that was getting displayed.

So to fix this, add the code piece:

```
#nav li:hover ul ul{
    display:none;
    }
#nav li:hover ul, #nav li li:hover ul{
    display:block;
    }
```

So what the above code is implying, when one hovers on the li element, the element 2 levels below needs to be blocked and when one hovers on the li element only the immediate ul element needs to be displayed.

check http://jsfiddle.net/sxzR8/1/ for a working sample.